# Converting C# Web Application to NodeJS w/ Express

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, node.js, express

Anyone have any experience/tips/gotchas with converting an existing C# ASP.NET MVC N-Tier Web Application that could provide me with a better context before jumping into a conversion myself?

Are there any real-world examples that illustrate a conversion with sources?

Comment: This isn't a straightforward conversion. Just about the only code you would be able to keep directly would be client-side javascript. All server-side code (including templates b/c of Razor) would need to be essentially rewritten. Any entity framework code would need to be rethought since ORMs in node work differently and the way routing works in MVC can be totally different than how express does it, depending on your route config. Essentially the only thing that might remain the same would be the idea of the functionality implemented by the website and the URL structure.

Answer (score 0):

*Tips:*

**Regarding MVC pattern**, I would recommend to decide first how you want to architect frontend. We used jade as server side template engines for html. Later on, we rolled out with angularjs and it was good amount of rework. As we are now using express as API & angular as client side web app.

**Regarding N-Tier**, I recommend you to use express routers which will take care of SOC.

**javascript stack**, I recommend you to check out [Mean](http://mean.io)(angularjs apps), [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/). We are not using it, but now almost ended up using all the bits what these stacks already have it.